# decimal-string() help xml/xforms

Tags: xml, xpath, xforms

i am trying to round a number to 2dp and i am struggling

i am trying to use the decimal-string method

This is what I had

```
<xf:bind nodeset="/stuff/price" 
    calculate = "if(boolean-from-string(/stuff/amountOff),
    ((/stuff/items) * (/stuff/duration) * 0.8),/stuff/items* /stuff/duration)" />
```

This is what I tried

```
<xf:bind 
    nodeset="/stuff/price" 
    calculate = "decimal-string(if(boolean-from-string(/stuff/amountOff),
    ((/stuff/items) * (/stuff/duration) * 0.8),/stuff/items* /stuff/duration)" , 2)/>
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? What problems are you encountering?

Comment: this is what i had
<xf:bind nodeset="/stuff/price" calculate = "if(boolean-from-string(/stuff/amountOff),((/stuff/items) * (/stuff/duration) * 0.8),/stuff/items* /stuff/duration)" /> 

and this is what i tried

<xf:bind nodeset="/stuff/price" calculate = "decimal-string(if(boolean-from-string(/stuff/amountOff),((/stuff/items) * (/stuff/duration) * 0.8),/stuff/items* /stuff/duration)" , 2)/>

Comment: What implementation of XForms are you using? This can be done quite easily if your implementation supports XPath 2.0 (e.g. Orbeon Forms). If not, I wouldn't be able to say as it has been a long, long time since I last used XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Standard XForms does not support a `decimal-string()` function, which implementation are you using? The full list of available standard functions can be seen [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#expr-lib) (notice that it also references [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#corelib)).

Depending on your choice of XForms processor, there may be an extension function that you can use (for instance, [formsPlayer](http://code.google.com/p/ubiquity-formsplayer/) exposes the [`format-number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225.aspx) function from MSXML), or you may have to define your own custom extension (e.g. in javascript) otherwise.